# Django in Docker: is GNU gettext tools only required in dev?

Tags: django, django-i18n

I'm building a Django app with Docker.

I have 2 `dockerfile`s, one for dev and one for prod.

To use Django's i18n, it's required to install "GNU gettext tools". I could add lines to `dockerfile.dev` to install this

```
RUN apt update
RUN apt install gettext -y
```

However, do I need this tool also installed in prod?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be necessary, as you're just using the gettext to create the translations and compile them.

hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).